# Can I ask this here (if not I am sorry!)? Laptop for coding

Tags: windows

I am currently looking for a laptop to use for university next year. I will be studying Computer Sciences and I am still debating which laptop I should get.

These where the laptops I had in mind:

- **Dell XPS 15 9570** (€ 1.829,00)

  - i7-8750H processor (4,1 GHz; 6-cores)
  - 16 GB DDR4, 2.666 MHz
  - 512 GB M.2 2280 PCIe
  - NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050Ti 4 GB GDDR5
  - 1920 x 1080 15'' display.
  - Up to 11h of battery life (97-Wh)
- **Asus ZenBook Pro UX550VD** (€1.599)

  - i7-7700HQ processor (3,8 GHz; 4-cores)
  - 16 GB SO-DIMM DDR4
  - 512 GB M.2 PCIe
  - NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050 4 GB GDDR5
  - 1920 x 1080 15'' display.
  - Up to 8h of battery life

The XPS has better battery life and has a better screen.

The ZenBook is cheaper, has more ports but has an older processor and CPU.

Maby their is another PC that is better. I would love to see different suggestions. Please note that since I am living in Belgium not every laptop is available here.

**I hope I can post this type of question on this website. I don't really know where else to post. If you are not allowed to post this on here, I am terribly sorry in advance!**

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Hello Kyle Uzerty and welcome on Stack Overflow I'm afraid this question off topic here. Please read [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You may want to take a look at this other Stack Exchange website: [Hardware Recs](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Good luck!

Comment: I believe this question belongs to  https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use for studies only then you could go for Asus. It is good anyway. If you want to have laptop for your job then go with Dell

Comment: Why is the Dell a better laptop for a job? Thank you!

Comment: You might need high configuration and high processor systems as the IDE's,Code and database will be very huge. And i think 4.1GHz is better option if u want to work with it in a IT company

Comment: @Manju Sounds logical. Thank you!

Comment: @Manju I did but it won't show up since I don't have 15 reputation.